# How to use switches in examdesign package

Tags: examdesign

I am reading the [`examdesign` class documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/examdesign/examdesign.pdf). On page 2, it mentions switches. I am trying to use the `\BoldfaceCorrectMultipleChoiceAnswer` switch. However, I don't know how to use it. The documentation says:

> Switches should be included in the preamble because doing so will
>   guarantee that they will apply to the entire exam.

So where should I put the `\BoldfaceCorrectMultipleChoiceAnswer` switch?

Comment: _preamble_ means between `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic structure of the document would be:

```
\documentclass{examdesign}
% Preamble -- use switches here
\BoldfaceCorrectMultipleChoiceAnswer
% End of Preamble
\begin{document}
% Document text here
\end{document}
```